# Convert this Sql Query to Postgresql please

Tags: mysql, postgresql

How can i use this in postgresql?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `current_date` and `date_part`;

```
postgres=# select date_part('month', current_date) as month,  
                  date_part('year', current_date) as year;
 month | year 
-------+------
     7 | 2020
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and extract the month.

```
select EXTRACT(month from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might be

```
SELECT * FROM atable
WHERE date_trunc('month', columnname) = date_trunc('month', current_timestamp);
```

That function rounds the timestamp down to the specified precision, in this case to the beginning of the month.